# B suggests A iff B Complement Doesn't Suggest A [DBertsekas P58 1.25(b)]

Tags: probability, alternative-proof

> Let $A$ and $B$ be events with $P(A) > 0$ and $P(B) > 0$. We say that
>   an event $B$ suggests an event $A$ if $P(A|B) > P(A)$, and does not suggest event A if $P(A|B) < P(A)$.
>
> 1.25(b). Assume that $P(B^C) > 0$. Show that $B$ suggests $A$ if and only if $B^C$ does not suggest $A$.

**Solution:** $\color{green}{P(B)}P(A) + \color{green}{P(B^C)}P(A)  \color{green}{= 1} P(A)$
(by the Total Probability Theorem) $\qquad = P(B)P(A | B) + P(B^C)P(A | B^C)$

$ \iff P(B^C) [ P(A) − P(A|B^C) ] = P(B) [ P(A|B) − P(A) ] \quad \blacksquare$

How and why would one discern or foreknow to write $P(A)$ in two ways as above? This "trick" feels guileful; is there an easier/more natural proof? Or could someone please demystify it?

I tried to prove via a string of equivalences: $P(A|B) > P(A) \mathop{\iff}^{?} P(A|B^C) < P(A)$.

$RHS \iff \dfrac{P(A \cap B^C)}{P(B^C)} < P(A) \iff \dfrac{P(A \cap B^C)}{1 - P(B)} < P(A)$.

but I don't savvy how to simplify the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but I'll walk you through one direction. I'm likely not doing anything that will prohibit the other direction from applying automatically, but I don't want to think about it.
I'll show $\mathbb{P}(A|B) > \mathbb{P}(A) \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A|B^C) < \mathbb{P}(A)$.

Obviously by conditional probability and simple algebra,
$$ \mathbb{P}(A|B) > \mathbb{P}(A) \Longrightarrow \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} > \mathbb{P}(A) \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) > \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B).$$

Now, we're going to do two things. First, we'll use the definition $\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C)$ to substitute for $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ on the LHS. Second, on the RHS we'll simply exchange $1 - \mathbb{P}(B^C)$ for $\mathbb{P}(B)$. This yields 
$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) > \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B) \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C) > \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B^C).$$

At this point we are home free. By simple algebra,

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C) < \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B^C) \Longrightarrow \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^C)}{\mathbb{P}(B^C)} < \mathbb{P}(A) \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A | B^C) < \mathbb{P}(A).$$

Now, unfortunately, we still had to pull in two different definitions, which might throw you off. However, I think it is more intuitive than the proof in the question. Hope that helps.

Edit: I see this question isn't recent and you probably don't need it anymore. Oh well.